# DLL function that exports a pointer do Delphi program

Tags: c++, delphi

I have a simple program that exports a DLL, this DLL exports functions from another DLL:

```
// SDK_DLL.cpp : 

#include "functions.h"
#include "functions_advanced.h" 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void DisplayHelloFromDLL()
    {
        printf("Hello from DLL...");
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) function_config FuncInit = appd_config_init();

    __declspec(dllexport) function_config * FuncInit2()
    {
        function_config* cfg = function_config_init();
        return cfg;
    }
}
```

The function_config_init() returns a pointer, I cannot seem to find a way of making this proper export declaration.

I am loading a simple function to Delphi this way:

```
procedure DisplayHelloFromDLL; external 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SDK_DLL\Debug\SDK_DLL.dll';
```

Will I need to change the way I am loading this pointer returning function?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The procedure is wrong because it gets the calling convention wrong. It's hard to know what you mean. You want to know the Delphi syntax for a function. Surely you'd find that in the documentation. You can't learn a language like this, asking these questions on SO. You can't hope to learn by an interop project either.

Answer (score 2):

`FuncInit` is an exported variable. Delphi does not support importing of variables via `external`, only of functions. If you need to import `FuncInit`, you will have to use `GetProcAddress()` directly to get a pointer to the variable at runtime:

```
type
  // you did not show the C/C++ declaration
  // of function_config, so I can't provide
  // a translation here, but it is likely to
  // be a struct, which is a record in Delphi ...
  function_config = ...;
  pfunction_config = ^function_config;

function GetFuncInit: pfunction_config;
begin
  Result := pfunction_config(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('SDK_DLL.dll'), 'FuncInit'));
end;

var
  FuncInit: pfunction_config;

FuncInit := GetFuncInit;
```

For purposes of interop across languages/compilers, the only portable calling conventions are `cdecl` and `stdcall`. When no calling convention is specified in code, the default used by most C and C++ compilers  is `__cdecl` (but can usually be specified in compiler settings), while the default used by Delphi is `register` instead (`__fastcall` in C++Builder).

When no parameters or return value are used, like in `DisplayHelloFromDLL()`, then declaring the wrong calling convention does not really matter. But when parameters and/or a return value are used, like in `FuncInit2()`, then declaring the correct calling convention matters. See [Pitfalls of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html#cconvs) for more details.

So, the two DLL functions in question would likely need to be declared like the following in Delphi:

```
type
  function_config = ...;
  pfunction_config = ^function_config;

procedure DisplayHelloFromDLL; cdecl; external 'SDK_DLL.dll' name '_DisplayHelloFromDLL';
function FuncInit2: pfunction_config; cdecl; external 'SDK_DLL.dll' name '_FuncInit2';
```

If the DLL uses a `.def` file to remove name mangling from the exported names, you can omit the `name` attribute:

```
type
  function_config = ...;
  pfunction_config = ^function_config;

procedure DisplayHelloFromDLL; cdecl; external 'SDK_DLL.dll';
function FuncInit2: pfunction_config; cdecl; external 'SDK_DLL.dll';
```